# How To Print A Specific Physical Size

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, silverlight

I'm sure this is a common problem, but I haven't been able to find it.

I have a website and I want the user to be able to print a rectangle on their printer that is 3.5 inches x 2 inches.  Exactly (within reason).

What's the best way to do this?

EDIT:  To clarify - I'm looking to print a bunch of multicolored Text within a rectangle that needs to be a specific physical size.  I also need to print specific shapes around some of the letters.

I'd looked into some of the .NET Printing stuff and found examples of measuring/drawing strings and shapes; but I didn't see anything that would let me specify a specific size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<div style="width:3.5in;height:2in;border:1px solid black;"></div>
```

CSS allows other physical sizes too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Rob P.        Are you trying to generate a print document like one might do with a WinForms application?  ASP.NET doesn't support printing quite like that - instead, you must render what you want to the webpage or provide an image or PDF or other document they can download and print.  There are options for printing directly, but they would require something like an ActiveX control.